# Can I render model properties in a form which uses that model as a foreign key?

Tags: django, django-forms

Given the following Models

```
class Camp(models.Model):
    camp_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    LEVEL_CHOICES = (
        ("junior", "Junior"),
        ("adventure", "Adventure"),
    )
    level = models.CharField(choices=LEVEL_CHOICES, max_length=9)
    CAPACITY_CHOICES = [(i, i) for i in range(1, 101, 1)]
    capacity = models.IntegerField(choices=CAPACITY_CHOICES)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    open_date = models.DateField()
    closed_date = models.DateField()
    fee = models.FloatField()

    def size(self):
        """Returns the number of registrations for this camp"""
        size = Camp.objects
               .filter(registration__camp_id=self.camp_id)
               .count()
        return size

    def is_full(self):
        """Returns False if size of this camp is less than its capacity,
        otherwise returns True"""
        is_full = False if self.size() < self.capacity else True
        return is_full

    def is_open(self):
        """Returns True if the camp is open for registration,
        otherwise returns False"""
        is_open = True if self.open_date 
                          <= timezone.now().date() 
                          < self.closed_date 
                       else False
        return is_open

    def is_active(self):
        """Returns True if the camp is currently in session,
        otherwise returns False"""
        is_active = True if self.start_date 
                            <= timezone.now().date()
                            <= self.end_date 
                         else False
        return is_active

    def __str__(self):
        name = self.name + " " + self.level
        return name

class Registration(models.Model):
    registration_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    # other fields omitted
    camp = models.ForeignKey(Camp)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.registration_id)
```

And the following Form

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Registration
        fields = ['camp']
```

Is it possible to make use of the various Camp model methods (for example is_full, is_open, etc) to choose which checkboxes are rendered in the template which a RegistrationForm instance is in the context of? Is there any way to access these methods via the RegistrationForm object in the view's context or the template?

Ideally I would like to hide any Camp instances for which is_open() returns false.
I would also like to render a HTML class attribute "waitlisted" for input tags on Camp instances that return true for is_full(). Something like

```
<input type="checkbox" class="waitlisted" ...>Camp Week 10</input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

You can access the QuerySet and methods for the model instances using the `.field.queryset` attribute of your form field as shown below.

```
{% for camp in registration_form.camp.field.queryset %}
    <p{% if camp.is_full %} class="waitlisted"{% endif %}>
        <label>{{ camp }}</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="camps" />
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

I believe this will only work with model methods which require zero arguments, but is sufficient for my needs.